# copy autounattend.xml to windows installation

Tags: windows, autounattend

Is it possible to programmatically get the "autounattend.xml" copied to the windows insallation during windows autounattended setup?

**My use case**

I have a USB-Stick with different unattended files for different configurations/scenarios:

- `autounattend-a.xml` for scenario "a"
- `autounattend-b.xml` for scenario "b"
- `autounattend-c.xml` for scenario "c"

which I copy/rename to `autounattend.xml` for the installation in a specific scenario:

e.g. `copy autounattend-a.xml autounattend.xml` for an installtion in scenario "a"

Once installed (maybe days later) I'd like to know which `autounattend.xml` configuration/file I used to install windows. Since the `autounattend.xml` in the USB-Stick might have been replaced for another installation I'd like to have a copy of it in the installed system.

My workaround at this moment is to copy the `autounattend.xml` to `sources\$OEM$\$1`.

Comment: You will have to give us more percise information.  Based on what you provided we can;t determine which file you renamed.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have luck finding what you need in the unattend.xml on the freshly installed machine. Try:

- C:\Windows\Panther\unattend.xml
- %WinDir%\Panther\unattend.xml

Or you could add a [RunSynchronousCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-deployment-runsynchronous-runsynchronouscommand) to your autounattend.xml file that would copy the autoattend.xml file itself to a less removable drive on the machine. Similar to the answer shown here:
[PowerShell script do not run from autounattend.xml file](https://superuser.com/questions/1772988/)

Comment: Hi, it is better to post the answer here and refer to links as a citation. When links disappear or change, your answer will become useless.

Comment: @ElectricChip: Thank you! The `C:\Windows\Panther\unattend.xml` is not really a copy of the original `unattend.xml`. It has (a) the comments removed and (b) the `<Password>` replaced by `*SENSITIVE*DATA*DELETED*`. That makes much more sense!